# Can you recommend me a Test Framework for an embedded Linux system?

Tags: http, testing, serial-port, automated-tests, embedded-linux

We are developing an embedded Linux system.

The system is accessed via serial port and ethernet/wifi (telnet and http to configure).

We are looking for a test framework that would support executing commands on the system via serial port and/or telnet and evaluate the results. Also executing commands from the host system to test connectivity with the embedded system (basic things like ping, open ports, etc...)

It will be a plus if the framework also supported some HTTP actions, like enabling a configuration via HTTP and then trying if it works via ethernet/serial/wifi.

We were planning about developing it ourselves, but it will be really nice if there was something available to save some time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had previously had success using DejaGNU http://www.gnu.org/software/dejagnu/ though I did not use HTTP actions (since it was not part of our system).

Comment: DejaGnu is rather dated technology. The answer was accepted, but I'd like to hear more opinions / alternatives.

Comment: Dated yes but it works and it works flawless for my needs :-)